# Focus from Custom Control to Next Active Control automatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to build a TextBox Custom Control In WinForm. I want to use this Custom Control or dll in my WinForms project. What I am trying, if I enter something in the custom control which length is say 2 then program will focus the next available control.
My dll or custom control Codes are below:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace cInputNumBox
{
    public partial class cInputNumBox : TextBox
    {
    private Int16 Val_Len;

        public Int16 ValueLength
        {
            get
            {
                return Val_Len;
            }
            set
            {
                Val_Len = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            base.OnLeave(e);
        }

       protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SkyBlue;
            base.OnEnter(e);
        }

        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (base.Text.Length == ValueLength)
            {
                ContainerControl cntrl = new ContainerControl();
                SelectNextControl(cntrl.ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
            }
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
        }

    }
}
```

I want to use this custom control to another project where focus will go automatically after entering something.
So far I've tried but the OnTextChanged is not working. Anybody Can help me out from this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control you have to pass as first parameter is the control at which to start the search. Since this your control, pass `this`:

```
SelectNextControl(this, true, true, true, true);
```

You can also specify the `ActiveControl` which is equal to the current control (`this`) in this case. Take the `ActiveControl` property of the current form:

```
SelectNextControl(FindForm().ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
```

If you create a new `ContainerControl` as in `ContainerControl cntrl = new ContainerControl();` this one will be empty and will not find any next control. `Form` derives from `ContainerControl` and does therefore have an `ActiveControl` property as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry I did not clear my question. Now I have edited my problem. I want to use this Custom Control or dll in my WinForms project. What I am trying, if I enter something in the custom control which length is say 2 then program will focus the next available control.

Comment: You already have that part, but are calling `SelectNextControl` the wrong way. You are calling it on an empty `ContainerControl`. The `ContainerControl` you must use is the one containing the controls to be selected. In this case this is the `Form`. Therefore call the `SelectNextControl` method of your form. Drop the part `ContainerControl cntrl = new ContainerControl();`! Instead, call `this.SelectNextControl(...)`.